# Freemarker - select option not saved

Tags: html, spring, freemarker

I have a form in my ftl file and one part of this is this select:

```
 <select id=”${spring.status.expression}” value=”${spring.status.expression}”>
    <$assign value=(spring.status.value!””) />
    <option value=”A” >A</option>
    <option value=”B” >B</option>
    <option value=”C” >C</option>
</select>
```

It is assigned to A by default what is fine, but when I click option B and then click submit, B won't stay selected, because it will be assigned default value A. How can I fix it ? I see some answers on stackoverflow but in php which I don't use.

Comment: Why don't you use the Spring Freemarker macros?

Comment: Could you show me how to use it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's build a common ground:

First, create a POJO to hold the information of your form

```
public class Foo {
   private String bar;
   // public getter and setter ommitted
}
```

Now, in your Spring MVC controller, put the instance you want to bind to into Spring MVC's model. This is done by annotating a method using `@ModelAttribute` which returns the required instance. Typically, you'll read current values for your form from a database - For the sake of brevity I'm just creating a new model instance here:

```
@Controller
public class MyController {

   @ModelAttribute
   public Foo readFooFromDB() {
     // read the current option from the DB or simply create a default option here
     Foo f = new Foo();
     f.setBar("B");
     return f;
   }

}
```

Spring will now put the `Foo` instance into it's model using the name `foo`. You could change that name by assigning another value to your `@ModelAttribute` annotation.

Next add a `@RequestMapping` method to your controller, which will forward to your Freemarker View:

```
@Controller
public class MyController {

   ....

   @RequestMapping("/request/path/")
   public String process() {
     return "mytemplate";
   }

}
```

Finally, in your template use Spring's FreeMarker macros to render a form including your select:

```
<#import "spring.ftl" as spring />
<form action="/request/path/">

  <#assign options = { "A": "Option A", "B": "Option B", "C": "Option C" } />
  <@spring.formSingleSelect path="foo.bar" options />

  <input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```

The form should now render the current value of the your `Foo` instance ("B" in our case) as the selected option.

So far, so good. Last step (the one you were originally asking for): If you submit your form, Spring should bind the submitted `bar` value to your `foo` instance. To achieve this, simply add the  instance as a parameter to your request method and annotate it again with `@ModelAttribute`. Note that the name of the parameter is important here and must match the name of the instance in Spring's model - `foo` in our case:

```
@Controller
public class MyController {

   ....

   @RequestMapping("/request/path/")
   public String process(
     @ModelAttribute Foo foo) {  // Binds all submitted request params to matching properties of your foo instance
     // validate your foo instance and probably save it in a DB
     return "mytemplate";
   }

}
```

Voilá