# Springboot+Freemarker: cannot properly send "select - option" value to controller from freemarker page

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, freemarker

I have a freemarker page with form which contains several single select options, which are taken from DB.

Here I send the list of options to the page:

```
@GetMapping("/download")
public String getDownloadMethod(ModelMap modelMap, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes){
    modelMap.addAttribute("filesList", dao.listAllFiles());
    modelMap.addAttribute("getFile", new Model());
    return "download-form";
}
```

Then there is the form:

```
    <form method="POST" action="/download-post">
<#if filesList??>
    <#if filesList?size != 0>
        <select name="files" value="getFile">
            <#list filesList as file>
                <option value="${file.id}">${file.id} -  ${file.name}</option>
                <br/>
            </#list>
        </select>
    </#if></#if>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Get File"/>
</form>
```

We select one of the options and the id of the selected option should be sent to the post method in controller:

@PostMapping("/download-post")
public String postDownload(@ModelAttribute("getFile") Model model, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes){

```
    redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message",
            "You successfully downloaded '" + model.getId() + " " + model.getName()+ "'");
    return "redirect:/downloadStatus";
}
```

Yet when I execute the code, I'm always getting "0" value of model.id and null of model.name

How should I properly bind the values in form so they would be sent to controller properly?

The difference [from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25775788/freemarker-select-option-not-saved) is that my list of option is not static but is selected from DB and there could be hundreds of options, which you cannot pre-define.

Comment: I have no routine with Spring MVC forms, but there are several strange things here. The HTML `select` name is `files`, yet the `@ModelAttribute` name is `getFile` (and, it's type is `Model`?). I guess they should be named identically. Also, HTML `select` doesn't support the `value` attribute.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but that template is way over complicated. Two `#if`-s in each other always can be united into one with an `&&`. But, you don't even need any `#if`-s, as you can just write `<#list fileList!><select ...><#items as file><option ...>...</option></#items></select></#list>`.